# Does anyone know how to connect a distant oracle database with Robot Framework?

Tags: oracle, robotframework

I tried to use cx_Oracle, but I couldn't install it, I have this message error : "cannot locate an Oracle software installation",
and yes, I don't have an Oracle server on my PC, I just have sqlDeveloper to test my queries.
But I would like to make some queries with robot Framework on this distant database, is this possible?

Comment: Are you using windows or linux machine to run the test cases?

Comment: windows, but I solved my problem by using the installer instead of pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully use cx_Oracle to access an Oracle database using the DatabaseLibrary. On a Windows platform, you

1. install [the thin client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html)
2. to the system PATH, add the path to the instant client folder
3. install cx_Oracle

Connecting to the database for our setup looks like this:

`Connect To Database Using Custom Params  cx_Oracle  user='bob', password='letmein', dsn='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sql1.mycompany.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=warehouse)))'`

Comment: I downloaded instantclient-basic-windows, set the system PATH, but now I have this message error when I try to install cx_Oracle : "distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files in C:\instantclient_folder"
Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you downloaded a different package/version of instant client than is required. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31308099/2532697

Comment: The above link suggests downloading instantclient-basic-nt, but I have been using instantclient-basiclite-nt successfully so either will probably do.

Comment: thank you , I don't know if it was a version problem because I tried several and it did not work, I still had the same message. I didn't mentioned that I used pip install, I tried to use the installer and it worked. So finally I think the solution was to use the installer, if you can change your answer by adding "also try to use the installer" or something like this, I could validate your answer. Now, there is a new problem, my request returns only cx_Oracle.OBJECT, so it's an another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Install [miniconda python distribution](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) which makes it much easier.
It comes with conda package manager as alternative to pip. Installing cx_oracle including instant client is then just this easy:

```
 conda install oracle-instantclient
 conda install cx_oracle
```

It will automatically download matching DLL files and place it to condo root directory. This way you do not have to stuggle with `ORACLE_HOME`, `PATH` variables and 32-bit vs. 64-bit mismatch of python and oracle DLL drivers.

Using it in robotframework example:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Basic database related keywords
Library  DatabaseLibrary

*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING} =  'user/mypasswd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myipaddress)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=mysid)))'

*** Keywords ***
Connect
    connect to database using custom params  cx_Oracle  ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}

Disconnect
    disconnect from database
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

2 solutions:

1. use odbc drivers and pyodbc
2. use jtds drivers and jaydebeapi:

   ${jdbcDriver}    Set Variable   '${jdbcDriversPath}/ojdbc6.jar'
   Connect To Database Using Custom Params    jaydebeapi     'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', ['jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SSID}','${database}','${DB_PASSWORD}'],${jdbcDriver}

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 32-bit versions of the following solved the issue for me:

- Instant Client Package - Basic
- Instant Client Package - SDK

I don't know for what reason but 64-bit versions of the Oracle client didn't work for me.